# Get pointer on var obtained via interface

Tags: pointers, go, interface, address-operator

In the following code

```
var a int
var b interface{}

b = a

fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", a, &a)
fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", b, &b)
```

output:

```
int, *int 
int, *interface {}
```

I would expect the type of &b to be a pointer on int.

I have two questions:

1) Why is it a pointer on interface{} ?

2) How could I get a pointer on the original type ?

Comment: Just a nit-pick/friendly piece of advice: avoid using `interface{}` as much as possible. It's a powerful tool, and sometimes you just can't avoid it, but it's a common mistake made by people who are new to the language to use `interface{}`  when they really shouldn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&b` => this is the [address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) applied on the variable `b`, whose type is `interface{}`. So `&b` will be a pointer of type `*interface{}`, pointing to the variable `b`. If you take the address of a variable of type `T`, the result will always be of type `*T`.

You cannot obtain the address of the variable `a` from `b`, because the assignment:

```
b = a
```

Simply copies the value of `a` into `b`. It wraps the value of `a` in an interface value of type `interface{}`, and stores this interface value into `b`. This value is completely detached from `a`.

In general, all [assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) copy the values being assigned. There are no reference types in Go. The closest you can get to what you want is if you store the address of `a` in `b` in the first place, e.g.:

```
b = &a
```

Then you can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get out `a`'s address from `b` like this:

```
fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", a, &a)
fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", b, b.(*int))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w8mq05EeOsX)):

```
int, *int
*int, *int
```

(Note: when you simply print `b`, since it is of an interface type, the `fmt` package prints the (concrete) value wrapped in it.)

See related questions:

[How to get a pointer to a variable that's masked as an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183561/how-to-get-a-pointer-to-a-variable-thats-masked-as-an-interface/41183899#41183899)

[Changing pointer type and value under interface with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342228/changing-pointer-type-and-value-under-interface-with-reflection/46342394#46342394)

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete [icza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592868/get-pointer-on-var-obtained-via-interface/54592908#54592908). In case if you don't know the type of the value stored in the interface (and, hence, you can't explicitly use type assertion), you can use [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package:

```
var a int
var b interface{}
b = &a
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))
```