# get pointer to element in list

Tags: go, pointers

My problem is that I need a pointer to an element of a list asserted as type `T`:

```
e *list.Element

t *T
```

But if I want to use type assertion, I can only get a copy of `e.Value`:

```
if instance, ok := e.Value.(T); ok {
    t = &instance
}
```

How do I get the reference to `e.Value` as a pointer to type `T`?

Comment: If a value of type `T` is stored, you can't. Store `*T` values, so you can type assert `*T` from `e`.

Answer (score 0):

If `e` stores a value of type `T`, you can't.

Store `*T` values in the elements, so you can type assert `*T` from `e`.

See related questions:

[Get pointer on var obtained via interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592868/get-pointer-on-var-obtained-via-interface/54592908#54592908)

[Cannot take the address of map element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321933/cannot-take-the-address-of-map-element/57322003#57322003)

[How can I store reference to the result of an operation in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197248/how-can-i-store-reference-to-the-result-of-an-operation-in-go/34197367#34197367)

[How to get the pointer of return value from function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744965/how-to-get-the-pointer-of-return-value-from-function-call/30751102#30751102)